# Need to re-edit .bash_profile but locked out because PATH is wrong

Tags: macos, command-line

I just added an incorrect PATH line to my .bash_profile and now every command results in "command not found", include vim.  How can I re-edit the file to make the correction?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the .bash_profile file? post it to take a look.

Comment: I wish I could.  That's the problem.  I can't run any command now.  How can I edit .bash_profile if every command ends that way?

Comment: mmm good question, perhaps open it with a non-command tool like notepad?

Comment: I was able to edit the file using TextEdit and used "Command/Shift/Period" to see hidden files.  Thanks for the nudge in the right direction.

Comment: glad to hear that it worked out =)

Answer (score 4):

Try specifying an absolute path to an editor:

`% /usr/bin/vim ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac you can also use the `open` command to have the OS open a GUI-based editor of its choosing (or have you select one.) I believe TextEdit is the default for .bash_profile:

```
% open ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: I dont think open will help in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

In the case command line tools won't work, files on most systems (eg. linux, osx, cygwin, etc) can be edited by non-command tools such as notepad. This tool, in contrast to Wordpad, is a plain text editor, while Wordpad is a word processor. In case some errors appear after using it, in the terminal simply runs:

```
dos2unix your-problematic-file
```

that should solve the problem.